# Boolean works on one side of my model, but not the other

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I have a case i am trying to cut out sections with a reference cylinder[image], but on the right side of the left axis the model cuts out from the reference, but on the left side nothing happens at all, please help.
It happens for other models too, where one side cuts out completely fine, but moving the cutout object to the other side results in a failed Boolean cut.
The normals are all facing outward as I did not mirror the object, but rather duped it and placed it on the exact opposite side of the OG object

Comment: Hard to tell without the file. Are there any modifiers on the cylinder? Is it using a mirror modifier or does it consist of two cylinder meshes, one on the left and one on the right? Any problems with the face orientation?

Comment: there are no mods on the cylinder, and there is no mirror modifier and the normals are facing out for both of them, sorry forgot to include that